# Pattern Tokenizer Factory not working with negation regular expression

Tags: solr, schema

I need my tokenizer factory , to split on everything expect numbers , letters , `&` , `:` and single quote character.

I use `Solr.PatternTokenizerFactory` as below,

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9&amp;-:]" />
```

but, its spiting tokens by space only . not sure what I am doing wrong in this.

can anybody help me on this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my mistake, that was very silly mistake, i need to escape `-` in my pattern

changed to below and its started working

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9&amp;\-:]" />
```